# How to access low level network API's inside an AWS Lambda Python function

Tags: aws-lambda, scapy

I'm trying to execute a piece of python code that attempts to send traffic over a `RAW_SOCKET` inside an AWS lambda function.

```
    tcp_header = struct.pack("!HHLLBBHHH", TCP_SRC, TCP_DST, 0, 0, socket.IPPROTO_TCP, 64, 0, 0, 0)
    ip_header = struct.pack("!BBHHHBBH4s4s", 0x45, 0x00, 0, 0, 0, socket.IPPROTO_TCP, 0, 40, socket.inet_aton(SOURCE_IP), socket.inet_aton(DESTINATION_IP)) 
    raw_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_TCP)
    raw_socket.sendto(ip_header+tcp_header, (DESTINATION_IP,0))
```

When I attempt to execute this, I get the following error

```
{
  "errorMessage": "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted",
  "errorType": "PermissionError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/ebpf_lambda_test/__init__.py\", line 23, in dataplane_test\n    raw_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_TCP)\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.8/socket.py\", line 231, in __init__\n    _socket.socket.__init__(self, family, type, proto, fileno)\n"
  ]
}
```

In an EC2 instance, I would execute this script with `sudo`, but how can this be done inside the lambda function?

Comment: If you genuinely need to do this then I think that AWS Lambda is not the right choice.

Comment: agreed, going to play with Fargate instead

Answer (score 2):

To create raw sockets, your process needs to have the capability `NET_RAW`, and Lambda runtime is not setting any capabilities whatsoever.

If you absolutely need it, you'll need to use Fargate which by default does set it.